# PostgreSQL & Delphi: Parameter data type

Tags: postgresql, delphi, parameters, firedac

I have a form to work with the dictionary tables. An user can modify the table by adding the new dictionary values. The code field of the dictionary table can be integer or varchar and I don't know for the particular table which type it is. Here the code for adding the new value:

```
Command.CommandText := 'insert into ' + VocOptions.Name + '(' + CodesField +   ', ' + ValuesField +') values(:code, :value)';
Command.Parameters.ParamByName('code').Value := eCode.Text;
Command.Parameters.ParamByName('value').Value := eValue.Text;
```

So, for the code field I always set the parameter as a string. It works with MS SQL Server, it determines the actual data type by itself. But PostgreSQL throws the error (type mismatch: integer and character varying).
How to resolve this issue with the PostgreSQL in the easiest way?

Comment: Try to use parameter substitution instead: `Command.CommandText := 'insert into ' + VocOptions.Name + '(' + CodesField +   ', ' + ValuesField +') values(:code, '+QuotedStr(e.Value.Text)+')';` In this case PostgreSQL also will try to convert string constant to the desired type.

Comment: This is not FireDAC's `TFDCommand`. What is it?

Comment: Hi, @Abelisto, your approach does work, thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Victoria! Actually it is TFDCommand inheritor. I migrated my code from ADO. To avoid remaking all the forms and replacing the ADO components with the FireDAC ones, I just wrote my own classes inherited from  TFDCommand, TFDQuery, TFDConnection with the addition of specific ADO properties. Now I can build ADO or FireDAC version of my application changing one conditional define.